# Why does defining new class sometimes call the __init__() function of objects that the class inherits from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, metaclass

I'm trying to understand what actually happens when you declare a new class which inherits from a parent class in python.

Here's a very simple code snippet:

```
# inheritance.py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Inside foo.__init__")
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)


class Bar(Foo):
    pass

print("complete")
```

If I run this there are no errors and the output is as I would expect.

```
❯ python inheritance.py                                                                                                                                                                               
complete
```

Here's a script with an obvious bug in it, I inherit from an instance of `Foo()` rather than the class `Foo`

```
# inheritance.py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Inside foo.__init__")
        print(f"{args=}")
        print(f"{kwargs=}\n")

foo = Foo()
class Bar(foo):            <---- This is wrong
    pass

print("complete")
```

This code runs without crashing however I don't understand why `Foo.__init__()` is called **twice**.

Here's the output:

```
❯ python inheritance.py
Inside foo.__init__        <--- this one I expected
args=()
kwargs={}

Inside foo.__init__       <--- What is going on here...?
args=('Bar', (<__main__.Foo object at 0x10f190b10>,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Bar'})
kwargs={}

complete
```

On line 8 I instantiate `Foo()` with no arguments which is what I expected. However on line 9 `Foo.__init__` is called with the arguments that would normally be passed to `type()` to generate a new class.

I can see vaguely what's happening: `class Bar(...)` is code that generates a new class so at some point `type("Bar", ...)` needs to be called but:

1. How does this actually happen?
2. Why does inheriting from an instance of `Foo()` cause `Foo.__init__("Bar", <tuple>, <dict>)` to be called?
3. Why isn't `type("Bar", <tuple>, <dict>)` called instead?

Comment: Off the top of my head, this feels like something that takes place to allow for a  `metaclass`. Rather than `Foo.__init__("Bar", <tuple>, <dict>)`, `type(Foo)("Bar", <tuple>, <dict>)` is called. With no `metaclass`, `type(Foo)` is `type`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is using `foo` to [determine the metaclass to use for `Bar`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass). No explicit metaclass is given, so the "most derived metaclass" must be determined. The metaclass of a base class is its type; *usually*, that's `type` itself. But in this case, the type of the only base "class", `foo`, is `Foo`, so *that* becomes the most derived metaclass. And so,

```
class Bar(foo):
    pass
```

is being treated as

```
class Bar(metaclass=Foo):
    pass
```

which means that `Bar` is created by *calling* `Foo`:

```
Bar = Foo('Bar', (foo,), {})
```

Note that `Bar` is now an instance of `Foo`, not a type. Yes, a `class` statement does not necessarily create a class.

Comment: Not that this answer needs it, but you can also prove this by attempting to instantiate `Bar`, `TypeError: 'Foo' object is not callable` or `print(type(Bar))`.

Comment: ~That `TypeError` confused me too. Why is `Foo` not callable. `Foo()`  works just fine?~

mmnn ok no okay`foo()` is obviously an error

Comment: I was going to, but then it seems all that does is prove that instances of `Foo` are not callable, which probably won't surprise anyone. Just mentioning that `Bar` *is* an instance of `Foo` seemed sufficient.

Comment: The type error is `'Foo' object is not callable` (i.e., an instance of `Foo`), not that the object `Foo` is not callable. (The error message could probably be clearer; it's not one of the improved error messages introduced in Python 3.11.)

Comment: Also, you'd get an error sooner if `Foo.__init__` didn't happen to accept all the arguments passed to a metaclass.

Comment: Is it possible to make alterations to `Foo` such that `class Bar(Foo()):` actually works?
Can I overwrite things like: `__class__` and `__new__` so that `Foo()` is a valid object to inherit from?

Comment: Hmm.. Why does making class from foo instance work, but `Bar = type('Bar', (foo,), {})` basically same class creation brings up TypeError?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "work". There's nothing special about `Bar` except for the syntax used to create it. It's otherwise exactly the same as any other instance of `Foo`. You can make `Bar` callable by defining `Foo.__call__`, but that will return what it returns, not magically make `Bar` a type.

Comment: @DiMithras Because `type` itself checks that the things you claim are base classes are actually classes (or at least things with metaclasses that are compatible with `type`). You get the same error with `class Bar(foo, metaclass=type): pass`.

Comment: Type instantiation itself isn't all that magical. `Foo()` is simply `Foo.__call__()`, with `__call__` being an instance method defined by `type`. The reason you get an instance is that `type.__call__` subsequently calls `Foo.__new__` to create an instance, which resolves to `object.__new__`, which *is* the magic interpreter-provided method that actually creates a new instance.

Comment: I reworded the answer slightly to refer to `Bar` (not the type `Bar`) being created, since the main point of the answer is that the `class` statement is *not* creating a type. `class` statements do not create types; they provide a declarative syntax for a sequence of method calls which *normally*, but not necessarily, result in the creation of a type.

Comment: `for a sequence of method calls`


How do I find out what the sequence is?

Comment: and where can I see the implementation of `type.__call__`

Comment: Start with https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation. The implementation of `type.__call__` can be found in the C source code for CPython, but for most purposes it suffices to assume it's something like `def __call__(self, cls, *args, **kwargs): obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs); if isinstance(obj, cls): obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs); return obj`.

Comment: And TL;DR: what end up as the result of the "class" statement is whatever the metaclass callable returns.  So: `class Foo(metaclass=lambda *args: {}): pass`  will give you an empty, plain, dictionary instance.

Comment: (one can see this being used in Python's stdlib own `typing.py` in things like `TypedDict`. Not only these, but they also needed to implement the `__mro_entries__` special attribute for the kind of hacks they had in mind there)